# Making CAML query Search Faster without using indexing

Tags: 2007

i have a caml query, in that query where condition is like this

```
<Or>
  <Or>
     <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='CourseCode' /><Value Type='Text'>" + searchText + "</Value>
     </Contains>
     <Contains>
          <FieldRef Name='CourseTitle' /><Value Type='Text'>" +searchText + "</Value>
     </ Contains>
  </Or>
     <Contains>
          <FieldRef Name='Description' /><Value Type='Text'>" + searchText + "</Value>
     </Contains>
 </Or>
```

It has a lot of Contains and the filed they are using cannot be indexed . Say for example 'Description' that is a mutiline column . This query is taking a long time to execute in a list having more 75000 items. Is there any way to make this fast wihtout using enterprice search . 
Can we use enterprice search for simple sharepoint lists ?
Mine is sharepoint 2007

Answer (score 3):

Enterprise search is a very powerfull system. Even though I've never done this before, I'm pretty sure, that you can define a search scope for your list using *Web Address* rule type (insert your list url there), and then use advanced search.

Here is an article about operating with search scopes:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/define-scopes-for-searches-HA101793666.aspx

Comment: Agreed - a custom scope and Search is the way to go.

Comment: +1, You'll probably also need to add custom Metadata Properties in order to query against your List's columns.

Comment: Is there any other work around or haack